# Load Webpage with login in java

Tags: java, http, authentication

I have a webpage http:/ /www.somesite.de This webpage gives me a file I want to download, but before I can do it I have to login with a username and a password. Can anyone tell me where I have to look for best practices for such a problem?

Thanks in advance

Sebastian

Comment: Is that the actual url of your website?

Comment: no sorry i edited it a little bit

Comment: I want to do something similar. Looking at apache http client to see if I can do it that way.

Answer (score 2):

so you are trying to download a file, but before you can download it you need to login?

you have 2 options:

- Log into the website manually, take all the cookies the website gives you, and right away  send the cookies using [apache common http client](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/), thereby pretending to be the session you just logged into with manually.
- Log in using commons httpclient by sending the form data, then then accepting cookies, and using those cookies to continue the session

Answer (score 0):

Check out [j_security_check](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&rlz=1C1CHMP_enUS291US303&ei=ZjV4Spj0GpWBtweG2NiWCQ&sa=X&oi=spell&resnum=0&ct=result&cd=1&q=j_security_check&spell=1). It's a very easy-to-implement feature of many servers.

Answer (score 0):

What's your web server. If you are using Apache httpd, take a look at this,

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/auth.html

Comment: it is not my webserver, it is any webserver, maybe the server where this site runs will change in time. I only know the username and password and want do programmatically login to download the page

Comment: That would be tough if the web server is not under your control. There are all kinds of login schemes they can use. I don't think you will find an universal solution.

If it's a form login, you just have to post the username/password in correct format and keep all the cookies. If they use HTTP Auth (looking for www-authenticate header), you probably need a library that support this. What do you use to fetch the file?